# bbc beta panorama with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, thumbnails

Just been looking at the bbc's beta homepage http://beta.bbc.co.uk/
and thought the panorama looked decent.

It'd make an interesting home page for a video site.

Has anyone seen something similar (open source) and preferably built with jQuery?

If not, any pointers on how best to achieve this without loading all the images at once (to reduce load time) but then load them once rendered so that the slide left or right works without delay...?

Comment: You do realize http://www.bbc.co.uk/ already looks like that (ie. it has came out of the 'beta')

Comment: They may still only be showing it to some users because I still see the old homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called carousel - there are million implementations out there for it. Just google for jquery carousel:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html

http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55

http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm

And so on...